# Why does arcpy.da.Describe return different keys for same feature class based on location?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, describe-object

I have a file geodatabase on a remote desktop with the following layer:
r'C:\Folder\Database.gdb\Feature_Dataset\Feature_Class'. If I copy this entire gdb to my local machine, da.Describe does not return the workspace property as it does on the remote desktop.

On the remote desktop:

```
desc = arcpy.da.Describe(r'C:\Me\Documents\Database.gdb\Feature_Dataset\Feature_Class')
print('workspace' in desc.keys())
True
```

On my local desktop:

```
desc = arcpy.da.Describe(r'C:\Me\Documents\Database.gdb\Feature_Dataset\Feature_Class')
print('workspace' in desc.keys())
False
```

This is from the python window in ArcGIS Pro 3.2 on my local desktop, and 3.1 on the remote. It's not just the workspace key that's different, though, and it makes it difficult to write python tools when the keys are different.

Is it because the remote desktop has enterprise? To be clear neither of these are sde databases - they're both file geodatabases.

Comment: No idea why that is happening, I tend to use `desc = arcpy.Describe(path)` and then `desc.catalogPath` to return the workspace. Personally I have never used the Describe method on `da` module. If you don't need it I would suggest  `arcpy.Describe()`.

Comment: da.Describe just returns a dictionary instead of a describe object. They're otherwise the same. arcpy.Describe(fc).workspace returns an AttributeError locally - functionally the same behavior as 'workspace' in desc.keys() evaluating to False.

Comment: Your method works when the target isn't in a feature dataset. When it is, I have to use the os module to split it. That's not difficult but I'm curious why there's a difference at all, and what other attributes/keys are going to be different because of it? It's frustrating.

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with "local" vs. "remote", probably related to difference in versions.

Comment: After testing on a Pro 3.1 machine right before upgrading to Pro 3.2, I can confirm the behavior difference is due to Pro versions.

Comment: @bixb0012 Thank you.

Comment: In Pro 3.1, the key doesn't exist in my tests, but it does in Pro 3.2.  Tests were done on same machine with same data sets.